# Eclipse minimal configuration for plug-in deployment

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing eclipse plug-in right now.
Default eclipse download contains a lot of plug-ins which my plug-in doesn't require.
It causes eclipse folder to have a larger size then it is needed.

So I wonder if there are any ways to create such minimal eclipse configuration, so it will be able to load my plug-in and be free of not require plug-ins? Are there any ways to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I wonder if there are any ways to create such minimal eclipse configuration, so it will be able to load my plug-in and be free of not require plug-ins? Are there any ways to do it automatically?

Of course. This "minimal base" is called **[Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform)** (Rich Client Platform).

Let me redirect you to [Vogella's tutorials](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html) on RCP - there you can read how to create and deploy RCP applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But what I really would like to know is how to cut off unnecessary plug-ins from Eclipse-rcp. For example you have deployed eclipse plug-in, dropped it in dropins eclipse-rcp folder. Then you want to run eclipse with only this one plug-in loaded(and required by this plug-in) while other plug-ins not loaded and even removed from disk.

Comment: Yah, I understood :) Please resort to that tutorial, especially the "Deployment" part - that's the way how you can create a "light" standalone runnable. And if you run your RCP app from within Eclipse and unnecessary plug-ins are loaded, then something's wrong with the set-up... maybe the run configuration or dependencies?