# Minimal run/debug configurations for eclipse plug-in projects

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-plugin, run-configuration

I am working on an eclipse plug-in project. Running/debugging the plug-in project in a standlone *Runtime Workbench* is a routine work. However, the runtime workbench launches and responds slowly, because my eclipse edition contains too many plug-ins.

> **Problem:** How can I create a minimal run/debug configuration without unnecessary plug-ins?

**My trial:** The option `Run As -> Run Configurations -> Plug-ins -> Launch with plug-ins selected below only` lists too many plug-ins to choose from. I am not sure what are required and what are unnecessary.
I try `Deselect All -> Add Required Plug-ins`, but it causes errors and fails to launch the runtime workbench.

---

The [post: Eclipse minimal configuration for plug-in deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4615546/1833118) seems related but it is focused on product deployment and I don't how can it be applied to my situation.

---

**Source:** You can find the plug-in project at https://github.com/hengxin/Eclipse-Plugin-Favorite-Demo. It simply contributes a `QualityEclipse -> Favorites` view.

Answer (score 0):

What if after `Deselect All -> Add Required Plug-ins`, **you check your application plugins** and then `Add Required Plug-ins` ? There might be few plugins to add manually though

Comment: It does not work either. Could not create the view in my application plugin. I am not sure what plugins are required (too many to choose from) to add manually. By the way, the chosen plugins by `Add Required Plug-ins` are strange to me (I don't think some of them are necessary for my application plugin; may be indirected dependent).

Comment: Well generally I take some time to list them all and do a feature of them, but when it's done you don't have do it another time and when exporting the product it doesn't take all the eclipse plugins :) So I don't have any magic solution ... maybe someone will !

Comment: @hengxin This should work. It sounds like you may not have all the required plugins listed in you plugin MANIFEST.MF files. I would normally expect there to be something like 150 plugins in list.

Comment: @greg-449 It is a simple plugin project and requires just a few plugins. And the `Automated Management of Dependencies` in `MANIFEST.MF -> Dependencies -> Analyze code and add dependencies to the MANIFEST.MF via Required-Bundle or Import-Package` says `no additional dependencies were found`.